Use custom MySQL2 connection pool into Knex - getting stucked
I am trying to pass a mysql2 connection pool to the Knex client by following the official documentation. However, the query execution seems to get stuck. Even though the insert query successfully inserts the data, it doesn't return anything and the code remains stuck. How can I resolve this issue?
Here's my code:
import knex from "knex";
import mysql from "mysql2/promise";

export const mysqlPool = mysql.createPool({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "user",
  password: "pass",
  database: "db",
});

const knexC = knex({
  client: "mysql2",
});

(async () => {
  // passing the pool to knex
  const res = await knexC("user").connection(mysqlPool).select("*");
  console.log(res);

  // pass a connection to knex
  const connection = await mysqlPool.getConnection();
  const newRes = await knexC("user").connection(connection).select("*");
  console.log(newRes); 
})();


If you use getConnection, you must also release it after you're done with. Why not let Knex handle your connections and pool though?

It is still not working with the release. By the way, I want to use same connection pool with Prisma (written an adapter for Mysql) and Knex. Just working on incremental migration from Knex to prisma.

Update your question to demonstrate how you released the connection.
